# Is cube root integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

This seems to be simple but I cannot find a way to do it. I need to show whether the cube root of an integer is integer or not. I used `is_integer()` float method in Python 3.4 but that wasn't successful. As

```
x = (3**3)**(1/3.0) 
is_integer(x)    
True
```

but

```
x = (4**3)**(1/3.0) 
is_integer(x)    
False
```

I tried `x%1 == 0`,`x == int(x)` and `isinstance(x,int)` with no success.

I'd appreciate any comment.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a sane way to do it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Ok!Is there any sane way then?

Comment: Not especially. I'd put/find an upper limit and keep a list.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams but it wouldn't be accurate in some extent.

Comment: I suspect you're encountering floating point rounding issues with your cube root. If your value differs from an integer by some tiny fraction, you'll see it as a non-integer. Try using a more float-appropriate test: `abs((x-round(x))/x) < epsilon` (for some small epsilon).

Comment: @Blckknght, thanks , I think ultimately I have to use some rounding methods. Given my numbers are somewhat big, I was hoping to find some other ways.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For small numbers (<~10<sup>13</sup> or so), you can use the following approach:

```
def is_perfect_cube(n):
    c = int(n**(1/3.))
    return (c**3 == n) or ((c+1)**3 == n)
```

This truncates the floating-point cuberoot, then tests the two nearest integers.

For larger numbers, one way to do it is to do a binary search for the true cube root using integers only to preserve precision:

```
def find_cube_root(n):
    lo = 0
    hi = 1 << ((n.bit_length() + 2) // 3)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if mid**3 < n:
            lo = mid+1
        else:
            hi = mid
    return lo

def is_perfect_cube(n):
    return find_cube_root(n)**3 == n
```

Comment: That seems good, but unfortunately my numbers are a bit bigger that $10^{13}.$

Comment: Then use the binary search approach.

Comment: For the binary search you can take the logarithm of the input and use it to compute an initial `lo` and `hi`, to restrict the search space.

Comment: `abs(n)  < 2**n.bit_length()` -> `abs(n)**(1/3) < 2**((n.bit_length() + 2)  // 3)` -> `hi = 2**((n.bit_length() + 2)  // 3)` e.g., for `n=10**13` -> `hi = 2**15 = 32768`

Comment: You don't need the point in `n**(1/3.)` in python 3. The division always returns a float there, so you can use `n**(1/3)`.

Comment: Thank you @MarkRansom, @jfs; I've revised the solution to include a logarithmic initial estimate.

Comment: Clever way of getting an upper bound for `hi` without using floating point.  You could probably do something similar for `lo` but since it's already O(log n) it probably won't make much difference.

Comment: @MarkRansom I considered it, but note that `lo` will be within a factor of 2 of `hi` within a single iteration, so it's not worth it unless the bound can be made very tight.

Answer (score 6):

In SymPy there is also the `integer_nthroot` function which will quickly find the integer nth root of a number and tell you whether it was exact, too:

```
>>> integer_nthroot(primorial(12)+1,3)
(19505, False)
```

So your function could be

```
def is_perfect_cube(x): return integer_nthroot(x, 3)[1]
```

(And because SymPy is open source, you can look at the routine to see how `integer_nthroot` works.)

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the answer by @nneonneo, one could write a more general kth-root function to use instead of cube_root,

```
def kth_root(n,k):
    lb,ub = 0,n #lower bound, upper bound
    while lb < ub:
        guess = (lb+ub)//2
        if pow(guess,k) < n: lb = guess+1
        else: ub = guess
    return lb

def is_perfect_cube(n):
    return kth_root(n,3) == n
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach using the [math module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html).

```
import math
num = int(input('Enter a number: '))
root = int(input('Enter a root: '))
nth_root = math.pow(num, (1/root))
nth_root = round(nth_root, 10)
print('\nThe {} root of {} is {}.'.format(root, num, nth_root))
decimal, whole = math.modf(nth_root)
print('The decimal portion of this cube root is {}.'.format(decimal))
decimal == 0
```

Line 1: Import math module.
Line 2: Enter the number you would like to get the root of.
Line 3: Enter the nth root you are looking for.
Line 4: Use the power function.
Line 5: Rounded to 10 significant figures to account for [floating point approximations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).
Line 6: Print a preview of the nth root of the selected number.
Line 7: Use the modf function to get the fractional and integer parts.
Line 8: Print a preview of decimal part of the cube root value.
Line 9: Return ***True*** if the cube root is an integer. Return ***False*** if the cube root value contains fractional numbers.

Comment: Let `num = (2**17)**3` and `root=3` -- the decimal portion is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

in `Python 3.11` you can use  `math.cbrt`

```
 x = 64
 math.cbrt(x).is_integer
```

(or)

or use `numpy.cbrt`

```
import numpy as np
x = 64
np.cbrt(x).is_integer
```

Comment: `math.cbrt((2**18)**3+1)` will test as being an integer even though the argument is not a perfect cube.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers aren't big, I would do:

```
def is_perfect_cube(number):
    return number in [x**3 for x in range(15)]
```

Of course, `15` could be replaced with something more appropriate.

If you do need to deal with big numbers, I would use the [`sympy`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sympy/0.7.5) library to get more accurate results.

```
from sympy import S, Rational

def is_perfect_cube(number):
    # change the number into a sympy object
    num = S(number)
    return (num**Rational(1,3)).is_Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [`round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) function to get the answer. If I had to write a function then it will be as follows:

```
def cube_integer(n):
    if round(n**(1.0/3.0))**3 == n:
        return True
    return False
```

You can use something similar to `int(n**(1.0/3.0)) == n**(1.0/3.0)`, but in python because of some issues with the computation of the value of cube root, it is not exactly computed. For example `int(41063625**(1.0/3.0))` will give you 344, but the value should be 345.