# How to find cube root using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is how, this is the best way, I have found:

```
x = int(raw_input("Enter an integer: "))
for ans in range(0, abs(x) + 1):
    if ans ** 3 == abs(x):
        break
if ans ** 3 != abs(x):
    print x, 'is not a perfect cube!'
else:
    if x < 0:
        ans = -ans
    print 'Cube root of ' + str(x) + ' is ' + str(ans)
```

Is there a better way, preferably one that avoids having to iterate over candidate values?

Comment: Since Python `3.11`, which will be released in a couple months, you can just use `math.cbrt(x)`, obviously having imported math first with `import math`. It will also cover the negative case, and will be more optimized than `x ** (1 / 3)`.

Answer (score 59):

You could use `x ** (1. / 3)` to compute the (floating-point) cube root of `x`.

The slight subtlety here is that this works differently for negative numbers in Python 2 and 3. The following code, however, handles that:

```
def is_perfect_cube(x):
    x = abs(x)
    return int(round(x ** (1. / 3))) ** 3 == x

print(is_perfect_cube(63))
print(is_perfect_cube(64))
print(is_perfect_cube(65))
print(is_perfect_cube(-63))
print(is_perfect_cube(-64))
print(is_perfect_cube(-65))
print(is_perfect_cube(2146689000)) # no other currently posted solution
                                   # handles this correctly
```

This takes the cube root of `x`, rounds it to the nearest integer, raises to the third power, and finally checks whether the result equals `x`.

The reason to take the absolute value is to make the code work correctly for negative numbers across Python versions (Python 2 and 3 treat raising negative numbers to fractional powers differently).

Comment: Question marked with python 3.x so not needed

Comment: There should be no need for  `round`

Comment: @PascalvKooten: What's your proposed alternative? Just `int()`?

Comment: @NPE Exactly, makes sense right?

Comment: @PascalvKooten: The code needs to round to the nearest integer, and `int()` rounds towards zero.

Comment: I thought int() just drops everything after .

Comment: @vaultah: Which is the same as rounding towards zero and which isn't what we want.

Comment: @NPE But the definition of a perfect cube is that it is an integer?! So why would you need `round`?? Show me a case in which it is needed.

Comment: Whoops, you're right, sorry :)

Comment: @PascalvKooten: The `1. / 3` is approximate. It's not exactly `1 / 3`. (No need to get worked up. ;-))

Comment: `==` does not require it to be exactly equal either, or does it? Hence: please show a case in which round is needed.

Comment: @PascalvKooten: Please put some effort into this debate, and don't just bombard others with random questions. :) **None** of the test cases in my answer work without the `round()`.

Comment: For example: `0.3333333333333333 == 1/3`. (True)

Comment: @PascalvKooten: Erm, `0.3333333333333333` still does not equal the mathematical one third, and hence the cube root is still approximate. As I said, rather than just guessing, simply experiment with the code.

Comment: `round(x)` returns `int` on Python 3.

Comment: it fails for `10**45` while ["binary search"-based answer works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23622115/4279).

Comment: 729.0**(1./3.)
8.999999999999998

Comment: What is the purpose of a decimal separator dot in `x ** (1. / 3)`? I also saw `1./3.` or `1/3.` in some other answers.

Answer (score 34):

The best way is to use simple math

```
>>> a = 8
>>> a**(1./3.)
2.0
```

**EDIT**

For Negative numbers

```
>>> a = -8
>>> -(-a)**(1./3.)
-2.0
```

Complete Program for all the requirements as specified

```
x = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
if x>0:
    ans = x**(1./3.)
    if ans ** 3 != abs(x):
        print x, 'is not a perfect cube!'
else:
    ans = -((-x)**(1./3.))
    if ans ** 3 != -abs(x):
        print x, 'is not a perfect cube!'

print 'Cube root of ' + str(x) + ' is ' + str(ans)
```

Comment: It will give a weird output if `a=-8` for example. Mines numbers will give you complex number outputs. Which is cube root of -8 = -2. Here the output: `(1.0000000000000002+1.7320508075688772j)`. It's a complex number.

Comment: @BhargavRao lol why you using two `-` ? It's turning it to back. `-8`'s cube root is `-2`. But your way output is `(1.0000000000000002+1.7320508075688772j)`

Comment: that weird complex number, is tecnically coorect.

Comment: Downvote because you show how to do math, not how to find out if it is a perfect cube.

Comment: @BhargavRao Hey you getting output correctly because you are multiply it with minest `-`. What to do when the user doesn't know the number is minest or not? Still not a correct answer.

Comment: The complete program is buggy. For example, it doesn't handle 2146689000 correctly (says it's not a perfect cube).

Comment: @NPE That is a shortcoming in python handling of decimal points... That is `2146689000**(1/3)` returns `1289.9999999999995`. *Sorry from my side*

Comment: a general way (pos and neg floats) is: (abs(a)/a)*(abs(a))**(1.0/3.0)

Comment: 729.0**(1./3.)
8.999999999999998

Comment: Use python3 code , not python2

Answer (score 10):

```
def cube(x):
    if 0<=x: return x**(1./3.)
    return -(-x)**(1./3.)
print (cube(8))
print (cube(-8))
```

Here is the full answer for both negative and positive numbers.

```
>>> 
2.0
-2.0
>>>
```

Or here is a one-liner;

```
root_cube = lambda x: x**(1./3.) if 0<=x else -(-x)**(1./3.)
```

Comment: 729.0**(1./3.)
8.999999999999998