# How can we make this code more efficient?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x=int(input("Enter an integer:"))
answer=None
cube_root_found=False
for i in range(0,abs(x)+1):
    if i**3 == abs(x):
        answer=i
        cube_root_found=True
if not cube_root_found:
    print(x,"is not a perfect cube")
else:
    if x<0:
        answer=-answer
    print("Cube root of",x,"is",answer)
```

I couldn't understand why we used answer=None and cube_root_found=False on the second line.And the other question is as i mentioned in the title :
How can we make this code more efficient?

Comment: As soon as you find a cube root, you can `break` out of the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find cube root using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014241/how-to-find-cube-root-using-python)

Answer (score 2):

I mean, there's a mathematical solution for this -- just cube root `x` rather than testing everything in `[0, x+1)`. No reason to loop in this case.

```
x = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
result = x ** (1/3)
if result == int(result):
    print("Cube root of", x, "is", result)
else:
    print(x, "is not a perfect cube")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for 9796532**3.  1/3 does not have a nice binary representation so there are rounding errors.

Comment: You could try both floor AND cieling.  The rounding errors will never be that much

Comment: @Scott you could enumerate through possible solutions around `result`, but ultimately working with large numbers causes floating point issues unrelated to your implementation. If you're expecting to solve for large numbers, that's a trade off you need to be conscious of.

Comment: Just checked.  4 is the first number that this happens to.  Viz. (4**3)**(1./3) != 4

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `break` after `cube_root_found = True` will make it short-circuit when it finds an answer instead of continuing.

```
x=int(input("Enter an integer:"))
answer=None
cube_root_found=False
for i in range(0,abs(x)+1):
    if i**3 == abs(x):
        answer=i
        cube_root_found=True
        break
if not cube_root_found:
    print(x,"is not a perfect cube")
else:
    if x<0:
        answer=-answer
    print("Cube root of",x,"is",answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through a bunch of integers, just take the cube root of your input and check if it is an integer.

so something like this:

`root = x**(1.0/3.0)
return root.is_integer()`

Comment: Same problem here.  This doesn't work for root = 9796532**3. 1/3 does not have a nice binary representation so there are rounding errors

Comment: using numpy should get rid of some of these errors. besides, I'm this is a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

`answer=None
cube_root_found=False`

We do this because, if `x` is 0, the for loops will execute 0 times. In that case, without the above code, we'll never assign a value to those variables, and

`if not cube_root_found:`

will fail with `"NameError: name 'cube_root_found' is not defined` message.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using *break*, I would suggest limiting range to *abs(x)/2* - unless it's either -1, 0 or 1.

Besides, I am not sure whether Python can optimize calling *abs* on each cycle on the same value - most probably not, so I would pre-store *abs(x)*

```
abs_x = abs(x)
upper_limit = 2 if abs_x < 2 else abs_x / 2
for i in range(upper_limit):
    if i**3 == abs_x:
......
```

Answer (score 0):

checking if `int(n**(1./3)) == n**(1./3)` does NOT work generally, since 1/3 does not represent nicely in binary.  try `abs(int(n**(1./3)) == n**(1./3)) < 0.000000000001`

Checking within a threshold is a normal way to check for equality in the presence of rounding errors. Note that (n+1) ** (1/3) -> n**(1/3) as n gets large, so this will give incorrect results for very very very large n.