# Python 2 is_integer not returning properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, isinteger

```
from fractions import Fraction

counter = 0;
a = int(raw_input())
b = int(raw_input())

if 1 <= a <= 10 ** 8:
    if a <= b <= 10 ** 8:
        for i in range(a, b+1):
            if float(i**Fraction(1,3)).is_integer() == True:
                counter += 1
                print(i)

print(str(counter))
print (str(float(64**Fraction(1,3)).is_integer()))
```

This code returns false which results in the if statement not being run at all. Furthermore, the cube root of 64 is 4, therefore, the result should be an integer. 
However, in the range between 1 and 100 inclusive, 1, 8, and 27 return true for this case. Any help would be appreciated as to why the cube root of 64 is not returning true.

Comment: You're running into the issue that floating point numbers are not very accurate - see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is cube root integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621833/is-cube-root-integer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 0):

You have used float for the cube root value. The following code gives you the value of `float(i**Fraction(1,3)) = 3.9999999`

Try rounding the value first before converting it to float.

`if float(round(i**Fraction(1,3),2)).is_integer() == True:`

Comment: I wouldn't suggest rounding first - this would return true for any value

Comment: Thanks Peter, I missed the floating point in the round function.

Comment: `float(round(0.5)).is_integer()` returns True though

Comment: `float(round(0.5,2)).is_integer()` returns FALSE.

Comment: That's better, but still worth mentioning the precision tradeoff

Comment: Note that `(a^3+1)^(1/3)=a+1/(3*a^2)+...` so that rounding to two digits will not be enough around `a^3=1000` and above, as `1001^(1/3)=10,0033322228..` confirms. For cubes close to the upper bound `10^8` one would need 6 digits after the dot.