# In Python RSA broadcast attack, why am I using bit length in this binary search for the cube root?

Tags: python, rsa, bisection

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23622115/9481613

Shows this function:

```
def find_cube_root(n):
    lo = 0
    hi = 1 << ((n.bit_length() + 2) // 3)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if mid**3 < n:
            lo = mid+1
        else:
            hi = mid
    return lo
```

My input for the function is `m`<sup>3</sup> the message cubed so that is why I need this function.
The `len(n)` turns out to be 454 vs. 1507 for bit length.

I kept trying to cap `high` at `num // 2` or `num // 3` which was not working but this works.  Why does bit length work here?

Comment: The part of the question with "I kept trying to cap `high` at `num // 2` or `num // 3`" is not intelligible, first because `high` and `num` are not part of the code, second because initializing with `hi = n // 2` or `hi = n // 3` results in code that's functional whenever `n > 5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm attempts to compute the cubic root of integer `n` using [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method). The context is the final step of [Håstad's broadcast attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_attack#H%C3%A5stad%27s_broadcast_attack), in which `n` can be thousands of bits, and is expected to be exactly the cube of an integer if all went well beforehand.

> Why does bit length work here?

The expression

```
hi = 1 << ((n.bit_length() + 2) // 3)
```

yields a rough approximation of the desired result, by taking the logarithm to base 2, dividing by 3 (with some offset), and exponentiating to base 2. Let's prove the result is always by excess:

1. For integer `n >= 0`, by specification of [int.bit_length()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length), `n.bit_length()` is the smallest non-negative integer `x` such that `n < 2**x`.
2. For every non-negative integer `x`, if holds `x <= ((x + 2) // 3) * 3`
3. The function which for input `x` yields `2**x` (that is two to the `x`<sup>th</sup> power) is nondecreasing
4. Therefore `n < 2**(((x + 2) // 3) * 3)`
5. By a standard property of powers, `2**(((x + 2) // 3) * 3)`is `(2**((x + 2) // 3))**3`
6. For every non-negative integer `i`, it holds `(1 << i) == (2**i)`
7. Therefore the initial value of `hi` is such that `n < hi**3` and `hi >= 0`.

The [loop invariant condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant) of the bisection algorithm

```
lo <= hi  and  (lo-1)**3 < n  and  n <= hi**3
```

is now easily established by induction: it hold before the while loop, and is maintained by the changes made in the loop (the proof uses that the function which for input `x` yields `x**3` is nondecreasing), hence is valid on exit. Bisection narrows the gap between `lo` and `hi` by a factor about 2 at each loop, and terminates with `lo >= hi`. It follows that on output the function returns the smallest integer `lo` such that `lo**3 >= n`, which is the integer cubic root of `n` by excess.